How to display 'error' when a power query is added to a sheet?
I have a  power query that when using the Power Query editor, shows error if bad data is entered in a spread sheet.  however when this query is added to a sheet,  it just shows blank.  Id prefer it show Error to give user feedback that something is wrong and likely they need to check their inputs.  Googling hasnt revealed how to do this.
I know i can replace these errors, but it only allows a numeric value to be repla
ced, which isnt going to help.
In the below case, the query combines data from multiple sheets, but one of the cell contained a '.' resulting in the Error cell.  Would like this to propagate to the sheet instead of being rendered as blank

THanks much if anyone knows how to do this.

replace the error with some obviously wrong but easily noticed number like 9999999999999999  IF it were text then the column returned to excel would be text as well

hmmm...im hesitant to do that as it would still factor into totals and aggregations..and these users might write a check for that amount.

You can only return text if the column iteself is text, and then the other numbers get returned as text as well

@horseyride yeah im realizing this.  was hoping maybe i could have done a division by zero or a formula error or something to fake it..wont even allow that

You can use try statement, for example:
WithNewColumn = Table.AddColumn(PrevStepTable, “NewField”, each try … otherwise “Error here”)

Change … for your formula
